# Django/Python - Check if argument was passed to class

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am passing different arguments to a Django form and would like check which argument was passed inside the form's class. How can i do that?

> views.py

```
...
form = CategoryForm(choose_category =True)
...
```

> forms.py

```
class CategoryForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.choose_category = kwargs.pop('choose_category',None)
        super(CategoryForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'

        if not self.choose_category:
            self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success'))

    if self.choose_category:
        do something
```

In the example above- the error is that `name 'self' is not defined`, how can i check for the existence of `choose_category` outside of `__init__` ?

This is rather a question of python, how can i check which parameters have been passed to a class from inside the class but outside of the `__init__` constructor. Also an answer such as - you cannot, it's stupid - is welcome if i get to understand the logical fracture i'm making:)

Thank you!

> EDIT: forms. py

Can't understand why this does not work and the fields don't display:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.Form)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.choose_category = kwargs.pop('choose_category',None)
        super(CategoryForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'

        if not self.choose_category:

            self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success'))
            self.onchange(False)
        else:
            self.onchange(True)

    def onchange (self, val):

        if val:
            category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset =Categories.objects.all(),
                widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'onchange':'form.submit();'}) ,
                empty_label= None,
                required=True
                )
            print('why doesnt it work this way')
        else:
            category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset =Categories.objects.all() ,empty_label= None,required=True)
```

Comment: The indentation is probably wrong. The `if self.choose_category` should probably be at the `__init__` level?

Comment: it can't be at __init__ level because there i'm going to set a field, such as: `cat =forms.ModelChoiceField(...)`

Comment: But outside the instance functions, is `class` land. And the point of classes is that it is one meta-level higher than instances. So as a result, they do can not take the `self` into account.

Comment: Your edit doesn't work because all you're doing is defining a local variable called "category". As soon as the onchange method finishes, the variable goes out of scope and is deleted. You still need to assign to `self.fields`, even in another method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you, it does make sense now. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing has to be done inside `__init__`. From there you can add or modify field definitions via the `self.fields` dict.

```
if choose_category:
    self.fields['cat'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=....)
```

Comment: Thx, i completely forgot about `self.fields`. However, i did come up with a solution which i still don't understand why it s not working, i'll edit the question right now to ilustrate it.